# Image caption not showing on slider

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a slider (imported from bootstrap) with captions on the bottom of the images using HTML and CSS, it does work on two images but not the third one.

Here's the code for the slider and the style.css portion that is used for the slider and caption.

HTML:

```
<!-------Slider------>
        <div id="slider">
        <div id="headerSlider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#headerSlider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#headerSlider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#headerSlider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="img/slider1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Portfolio">
         <div class="carosuel-caption">
         <h5>A random caption</h5>
        </div>
      </div>

    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="img/slider2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Portfolio">
       <div class="carosuel-caption">
         <h5>A random caption 1</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="img/slider3.jpg" class="d-block img-fluid" alt="Portfolio">
       <div class="carosuel-caption">
         <h5>A random caption 2</h5>
        </div>
    </div>

  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#headerSlider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#headerSlider" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#slider
{
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 800px;
}
.carosuel-caption
{
    top: 100%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    bottom: initial!important;
}
.carosuel-caption h5
{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 42px;
}
.carousel-item
{
     width: 80%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: black;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-top: 5%;
}
```

Picture of the slider:
[Working slider image with caption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4CsK.png)
[The slide in which it has no caption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hITUR.png)

I apologize if I missed something in the post.

Comment: Why are you using w-100 on the first two and not on the third?

Comment: w-100 was used by default in the bootstrap code, I tried to use img-fluid to see if it would fix it but it did not.

Comment: Have you tried using w--100 on the third?

Comment: The picture is bigger, caption still not shown.
The caption appears when I use w-50, but the image is too small.

Comment: I'm confused. It runs perfectly here: https://codepen.io/yaad-mohammad/pen/BaydbOr

Comment: I tried to set height to 350px and the caption did show up, but the first two images' captions are perfectly aligned while the one with the problem is kind of in the bottom now. Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: One possible cause could be the size of the third image. Try replacing the third image with the first image and see if it works. If it does, the image size is the issue.

Comment: I fixed the issue by adding this:

.carousel-item img
{
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
}

Comment: Awesome! Then it def was image size!

Comment: Pretty much, thanks for your help!